# why \b doesn't work in python re module?

Tags: python, regex

It is known that `\b` means word boundary in regular expression. However the following code of `re` module in python doesn't work:

```
>>> p=re.compile('\baaa\b')
>>> p.findall("aaa vvv")
[]
```

I think the returned results of `findall` should be `["aaa"]`, however it didn't find anything. What's the matter?

Comment: (Single quotes disabling escapes isn’t a Python thing; the two types are equivalent.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to use a raw string, or else the `\b` is interpreted as a string escape.  Use `r'\baaa\b'`.  (Alternatively, you can write `'\\b'`, but that is much more awkward for longer regexes.)

Comment: I got it. Thank you for the timely answer!